# Python asyncio: how to mock __aiter__() method?

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, python-asyncio, aiohttp, python-unittest.mock

I have a code which is listening to messages on WebSocket using [`aiohttp`](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/web_reference.html#websocketresponse).

It looks like:

```
async for msg in ws:
    await self._ws_msg_handler.handle_message(ws, msg, _services)
```

Where `ws` is an instance of `aiohttp.web.WebSocketResponse()` ([original code](https://github.com/f0t0n/aiojsonrpc/blob/37a1c2561a846efe465fcb919582f1b54199d346/aiojsonrpc/request_handler.py#L113))

In my test I mock `WebSocketResponse()` and its `__aiter__` method:

```
def coro_mock(**kwargs):
    return asyncio.coroutine(mock.Mock(**kwargs))


@pytest.mark.asyncio
@mock.patch('aiojsonrpc.request_handler.WebSocketMessageHandler')
async def test_rpc_websocket_handler(
    MockWebSocketMessageHandler,
    rpc_websocket_handler
):

    ws_response = 'aiojsonrpc.request_handler.WebSocketResponse'
    with mock.patch(ws_response) as MockWebSocketResponse:
        MockRequest = mock.MagicMock()
        req = MockRequest()

        ws_instance = MockWebSocketResponse.return_value
        ws_instance.prepare = coro_mock()
        ws_instance.__aiter__ = coro_mock(return_value=iter(range(5)))
        ws_instance.__anext__ = coro_mock()

        handle_msg_result = 'Message processed'
        MockWebSocketMessageHandler.handle_message.side_effect = Exception(
            handle_msg_result)
        msg_handler = MockWebSocketMessageHandler()

        with pytest.raises(Exception) as e:
            await request_handler.RpcWebsocketHandler(msg_handler)(req)
        assert str(e.value) == handle_msg_result
```

Though when I run the [test](https://github.com/f0t0n/aiojsonrpc/blob/37a1c2561a846efe465fcb919582f1b54199d346/tests/test_request_handler.py#L251) it fails with the error message saying:

> 'async for' requires an object with `__aiter__` method, got MagicMock

```
=================================================================================== FAILURES ===================================================================================
__________________________________________________________________________ test_rpc_websocket_handler __________________________________________________________________________

MockWebSocketMessageHandler = <MagicMock name='WebSocketMessageHandler' id='140687969989632'>
rpc_websocket_handler = <aiojsonrpc.request_handler.RpcWebsocketHandler object at 0x7ff47879b0f0>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    @mock.patch('aiojsonrpc.request_handler.WebSocketMessageHandler')
    async def test_rpc_websocket_handler(
        MockWebSocketMessageHandler,
        rpc_websocket_handler
    ):

        ws_response = 'aiojsonrpc.request_handler.WebSocketResponse'
        with mock.patch(ws_response) as MockWebSocketResponse:
            # MockRequest = mock.create_autospec(aiohttp.web_reqrep.Request)
            # req = MockRequest(*[None] * 6)
            MockRequest = mock.MagicMock()
            req = MockRequest()

            ws_instance = MockWebSocketResponse.return_value
            ret = mock.Mock()
            ws_instance.prepare = coro_mock()
            ws_instance.__aiter__ = coro_mock(return_value=iter(range(5)))
            ws_instance.__anext__ = coro_mock()

            handle_msg_result = 'Message processed'
            MockWebSocketMessageHandler.handle_message.side_effect = Exception(
                handle_msg_result)
            msg_handler = MockWebSocketMessageHandler()

            with pytest.raises(Exception) as e:
                await request_handler.RpcWebsocketHandler(msg_handler)(req)
>           assert str(e.value) == handle_msg_result
E           assert "'async for' ...got MagicMock" == 'Message processed'
E             - 'async for' requires an object with __aiter__ method, got MagicMock
E             + Message processed

tests/test_request_handler.py:252: AssertionError
```

So it behaves like `__aiter__()` was never mocked.
How I'm supposed to accomplish correct mocking in this case?

---

**Update:**

For now I've found a [workaround](https://github.com/f0t0n/aiojsonrpc/pull/1/commits/deb80fbf0bf6f3687a2569057a5151f086a8b897#diff-5b5b170d5baa5e91e7556ad1d80c836bR113) to make the code testable though I would really appreciate if someone tell me how to deal with the issue described in the original question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make the mocked class return an object implementing the expected interface:

```
class AsyncIterator:
    def __init__(self, seq):
        self.iter = iter(seq)

    def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            return next(self.iter)
        except StopIteration:
            raise StopAsyncIteration

MockWebSocketResponse.return_value = AsyncIterator(range(5))
```

I don't think there is a way (yet) to correctly mock an object implementing `__aiter__`, it may be a python bug, as `async for` rejects a `MagicMock`, even if `hasattr(the_magic_mock, '__aiter__')` is `True`.

**EDIT (13/12/2017)**: the library asynctest supports asynchronous iterators and context managers since 0.11, asynctest.MagicMock provides this feature for free.

Comment: Thanks Martin. [It works for me](https://coveralls.io/builds/5858130). And better I'll  keep the code clear than one test case.

Comment: works here too; note that i had to add `def __call__` soas to make it callable. thanks Martin!

Comment: Thank god that StackOverflow still exists! :sweat-smile

Answer (score 8):

For posterity, I had the same problem of needing to test an `async for` loop, but the accepted solution doesn't seem to work for Python 3.7.  The example below works for `3.6.x` and `3.7.0`, but *not* for `3.5.x`:

```
import asyncio


class AsyncIter:    
    def __init__(self, items):    
        self.items = items    

    async def __aiter__(self):    
        for item in self.items:    
            yield item    


async def print_iter(items):
    async for item in items:
        print(item)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    things = AsyncIter([1, 2, 3])
    loop.run_until_complete(print_iter(things))
    loop.close()
```

With the above, mocking it looks something like:

```
with mock.patch('some.async.iter', return_value=AsyncIter([1, 2, 3])):
  # do test requiring mocked iter
```

Answer (score 7):

Works for py38

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

async def test_iterable(self):
    loop_iterations = 0
    mock = MagicMock()
    mock.__aiter__.return_value = range(5)
    async for _ in mock:
        loop_iterations += 1

    self.assertEqual(5, loop_iterations)
```

Comment: Nice and clean, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have a python version that supports `AsyncMock` and I also leverage `pytest_mock`. I came up with this solution to this problem combining the use of `AsyncMock` `side_effect`:

```py
from typing import List
import pytest
import asyncio

from pytest_mock.plugin import MockerFixture


pytestmark = pytest.mark.asyncio


async def async_generator(numbers: List[int]):
    for number in numbers:
        yield number
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def function_to_test(numbers: List[int]):
    async for thing in async_generator(numbers):
        yield thing * 3
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)


async def test_async_generator(mocker: MockerFixture):
    mock_numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    async def async_generator_side_effect(numbers: List[int]):
        for number in numbers:
            yield number

    mock_async_generator = mocker.patch("tests.test_async_generator.async_generator")
    mock_async_generator.side_effect = async_generator_side_effect

    actual = []
    async for result in function_to_test(mock_numbers):
        actual.append(result)

    assert actual == [3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```